# Phone state listener called multiple times

Tags: android

hi i want to log the incoming number to the database. i am using broadcast receiver to listen for phone calls and using phone state listener.
here is my code

ThePhoneStateListener.java

```
package com.example.netlogger.Receiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class ThePhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context context;
    public ThePhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
            Log.d("TAGG", "Insert: " + incomingNumber);
        }

    }
}
```

CallActionReceiver.java

```
package com.example.netlogger.Receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallActionsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) arg0
                .getSystemService(arg0.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        manager.listen(new ThePhoneStateListener(arg0),
                android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

Menifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.netlogger.Receiver.CallActionsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in `ThePhoneStateListener`onCallStateChanged() why it is called multiple times. i want to insert incoming number to database just once.

Comment: what is the use of callactionlistener

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some how , i solved it. the problem is that when ever my broadcast receiver's onReceive() was invoked ,every time i was trying to listen  a new PhoneStateListener.You just need to do it once. just like following

```
package com.example.netlogger.Receiver;

import java.util.Date;

import com.example.netlogger.util.LocalDatabase;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallActionsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static ThePhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) arg0
                .getSystemService(arg0.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);      
        if (phoneStateListener == null) {
            phoneStateListener = new ThePhoneStateListener(arg0);
            manager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }


    }

}
```

Problem solved. Cheers

Comment: Great solution with this static variable use.

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your solution, but it worked for me when I implemented singleton object of my `PhoneStateListener` class. `onReceive` in my BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (phoneListener == null) {
        phoneListener = CallStateListener.getCallStateInstance(context);CallStateListener(context);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, android.telephony.PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

and this is method in my PhoneStateListener class:

```
public static CallStateListener getCallStateInstance(Context ctx) {
    if (callStateInstance == null)
        callStateInstance = new CallStateListener(ctx);

    return callStateInstance;
}
```

hope it will be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I am simply create static variable and check

```
 public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static String canEndCall;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (canEndCall == null)
        {
            TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tmgr.listen(new PhoneStateListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
                {

                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            canEndCall = "...";
        }
    }
```