# Broadcast Receiver running 2 times

Tags: java, android

My app using broadcast to receive state of phone call, then it pass state to service to make a record call.
The problem is that state Off-Hook is always running 2 times. It's lead to my service record 2 times.
How can I fix this?

MyBroadCastReceiver.class

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AutoRecordService.class);
            intent1.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            intent1.putExtra("inputExtra", "Screen rights");
            switch (state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    intent1.setAction("IDLE");
                    Log.i(TAG, "onIdle: ");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    intent1.setAction("RINGING");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    intent1.setAction("OFFHOOK");
                    Log.i(TAG, "onOffhook: ");
                    break;
                default:
                    intent1.setAction("OUTGOINGCALL");
                    break;
            }
            context.startService(intent1);
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem by changing `phoneStateListener` to static and check if it is null. Because listener receives phone state many times, so void `onReceive` always run 4 or 5 times.

Got so many help at this answer
[Phone state listener called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016603/phone-state-listener-called-multiple-times)

Problem solved ^^

**EDIT**

This is my code

```
private static PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener;
```

Then in my 'onReceive', put condition statement to check null for 'phoneStateListener'.

```
if (phoneStateListener==null){
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AutoRecordService.class);
                intent1.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                switch (state){
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        intent1.setAction("IDLE");
                        Log.i(TAG, "onIdle: ");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        intent1.setAction("RINGING");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        intent1.setAction("OFFHOOK");
                        Log.i(TAG, "onOffhook: ");
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent1.setAction("OUTGOINGCALL");
                        break;
                }
                context.startService(intent1);
            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.